# Do stunt doubles go to movies where the actor lookalikes go?

Tags: stunts, acting

Since stunt doubles look somewhat similar to the actors they're replacing for the dangerous stunts, does this mean they tend to gravitate to films where they know their lookalikes are going, since that's what they're best at?

Comment: Hello and welcome!   I'm afraid that this question might be in danger of being closed due to it being opinion based.  Nobody can answer the question as it is unless they knew the intentions of every stunt double.  Thank you for taking the time to contribute to this site :)

Comment: @steelershark I guess its more of a matter o how does the stunt job work (which I have no clue). Are the same usually hired to work for an actor, or do they audition every time, or another option?

Comment: @LeonFreire Well, I would suggest the OP to ask something along the lines of "Is there any evidence that stunt doubles stay with the same actors throughout their career?"  Or like you said...maybe their agents are informed about certain stunt jobs for certain actors.  It's an interesting question if it can just be tweaked a little :)

Comment: I don't know that most stunt doubles look much like the people they're doubling for. All they need is similar body types and a wig. Any closeups that involve the face will likely be shot with the actual actor.

Comment: @Catija They don't need to have too much similar faces. All I know is that it helps if they have a decently similar profile. I know that at least most of the ones I have seen usually work out to have a body type similar to their respective actors and try to match the skin tone (tanning, makeup, or whatever). But that is for the looks. I don't actually know how they get hired for the job.

Comment: @LeonFreire that's pretty much what I said.

Comment: @Catija I just elaborated a little more on it, and I'm just saying that I think the focus of the question is not much about how the appearance works, but how do they get the job.

Answer (score 5):

In Hollywood, stunt-doubles rarely work like that. Actors and actresses don't tend to have the same stunt double for the rest of their life.

This is because there is a more cost-efficient solution to this - makeup! Look up behind-the-scenes footage of *any* action movie, and you'll see what I mean. In their own time, doubles don't look anything like the actor, but with a tonne of make-up and hair-styling, filmmakers can essentially merge their faces on screen, although not with perfection. That's why their faces are barely shown on-screen, if at all. Take for instance T2: Judgement Day. If you pause the movie at certain parts, you'll notice obvious stunt doubles that aren't perfections, but you missed because the director cleverly made you focus on something other than his face.

[image: obvious stunt double]

And this saves a lot of money, because this would mean you don't have to depend on the same stunt-double, who is likely to demand a salary raise.

Comment: I recently watched this very movie in HD for the first time, and was shocked at how conspicuous it was that whoever was driving the motorcycle during the "jump" in that scene was just wearing an Arnold mask or something.